# How do I create perfect stroke-dash spacing for a rounded rectangle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, figma

So I'm trying to recreate this rectangle from Ikea:

[image]

I found this article on how to calculate dashes: https://www.designernews.co/stories/47034-how-can-we-calculate-a-perfect-dashed-border-in-sketch

But I still can't get it quite right:

[image]

My rect is 242 X 162 with a 16px radius. Is this possible or do I just need to create it myself through custom vectors?

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah shoot, sorry about that. Didn't realize it was a 'lightbox' overlay instead of a separate page. Edited the link!

Comment: I've turned these into actual images in the question, just in case the links rot over time.

Comment: are you using illustrator of figma? you tagged both in the question

Answer (score 1):

I would do this manually. The example below was made in Illustrator, but should be possible in any vector image editor.

1. Create a rounded rectangle, and copy it using Ctrl+C
2. Add some anchors using guides to help, then select and deleted the gap segments
3. Finally paste the copy back in place and reduce its opacity.

Example

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Was just wondering if there was an easy way to do this with the dashes, since I have to do several of these with different dimensions and shapes. Thanks!

Comment: @aalok89 In Illustrator, if you apply a dash to a stroke, the problem is that if you then round the corners, it changes the perimeter size and messes up the position of the dashes. You could instead Expand the Appearance of a non-round cornered rectangle, and then round the corners using the round corner widgets.